# Datetime sem o ano

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou precisando representar feriados e na minha classe feriado eu preciso definir a data de inicio e fim do feriado. Como data de inicio e fim eu preciso informar somente o *mês, dia, hora e minuto*. Porém a classe **datetime** do python exige que o ano seja informado.
Existe alguma forma de criar um objeto **datetime** sem o ano? Visto que para feriados o ano não importa.
Eu poderia criar minha própria classe datetime, mas como vou precisar fazer comparações de data eu teria que sobrecarregar operadores, mas não quero ter que reinventar a roda.

```
class Feriado:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Eu poderia criar minha própria classe datetime, mas como vou precisar fazer comparações de data eu teria que sobrecarregar operadores, mas não quero ter que reinventar a roda

A não ser que compare datas sem ano somente com outras datas sem ano, não vejo um modo simples de fugir disso. Não tem que ser, complicado, porém:

```
from datetime import datetime

class Feriado(datetime):

    # Na criação de uma nova classe, adicionamos um ano qualquer aos argumentos, para que possamos
    # ser uma classe derivada de datetime.
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['year'] = 1970
        return super(Feriado, cls).__new__(Feriado, *args, **kwargs)

    # Fazemos uma cópia do outro datetime ao qual comparamos, mas setamos o ano como o mesmo
    # ano de nosso feriado (assim efetivamente comparamos só dia/mês/hora)
    def __lt__(self, other):
        equivalente = other.replace(year=self.year)
        return super().__lt__(equivalente)

    def __le__(self, other):
        equivalente = other.replace(year=self.year)
        return super().__le__(equivalente)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        equivalente = other.replace(year=self.year)
        return super().__gt__(equivalente)

    def __ge__(self, other):
        equivalente = other.replace(year=self.year)
        return super().__ge__(equivalente)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        equivalente = other.replace(year=self.year)
        return super().__eq__(equivalente)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        equivalente = other.replace(year=self.year)
        return super().__ne__(equivalente)

natal = Feriado(day=25, month=12)
aniversario_florianopolis = Feriado(day=23, month=3)

if natal > datetime.now():
    print('O natal ainda não chegou :(')

if aniversario_florianopolis < datetime.now():
    print('O aniversário de Florianópolis já passou :(')
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a função `timedelta()` da bliblioteca padrão `datetime` para para trabalhar com um período de tempo ao invés de trabalhar com datas específicas, vejá só:

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta

data_inicial = date.today();
data_final = data_inicial + timedelta(days=60);

print( data_inicial )
print( data_final )
```

Saída:

```
2018-05-25
2018-07-24
```

[Feriados Móveis](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feriado_m%C3%B3vel) tais como a Páscoa, Carnaval, Sexta-feira Santa, Quarta-feira de Cinzas e Corpus Christi dependem do Ano para serem calculados.

Você pode usar o [`Algoritmo de Butcher`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A1lculo_da_P%C3%A1scoa#Algoritmo_de_Meeus/Jones/Butcher) para calcular o feriado da Páscoa, para então calcular os demais, veja só como ficaria a classe `Feriado`:

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta

class Feriado:

    def __init__( self, ano = date.today().year ):
        a = ano % 19
        b = ano // 100
        c = ano % 100
        d = (19 * a + b - b // 4 - ((b - (b + 8) // 25 + 1) // 3) + 15) % 30
        e = (32 + 2 * (b % 4) + 2 * (c // 4) - d - (c % 4)) % 7
        f = d + e - 7 * ((a + 11 * d + 22 * e) // 451) + 114
        mes = f // 31
        dia = f % 31 + 1
        self.data_pascoa = date( ano, mes, dia )
        self.ano = ano

    def ano_novo( self ):
        return date( self.ano, 1, 1 )

    def sexta_feira_santa( self ):
        return self.data_pascoa - timedelta(days=2)

    def cinzas( self ):
        return self.data_pascoa - timedelta(days=46)

    def carnaval( self ):
        return self.data_pascoa - timedelta(days=47)

    def pascoa( self ):
        return self.data_pascoa

    def tirandentes( self ):
        return date( self.ano, 4, 21 )

    def trabalho( self ):
        return date( self.ano, 5, 1 )

    def corpus_christi( self ):
        return self.data_pascoa + timedelta(days=60)

    def independencia( self ):
        return date( self.ano, 9, 7 )

    def nossa_senhora( self ):
        return date( self.ano, 10, 12 )

    def finados( self ):
        return date( self.ano, 11, 2 )

    def proclamacao_republica( self ):
        return date( self.ano, 11, 15 )

    def natal( self ):
        return date( self.ano, 12, 25 )

    def todos( self ):
        return [
            self.ano_novo(),
            self.carnaval(),
            self.cinzas(),
            self.sexta_feira_santa(),
            self.pascoa(),
            self.tirandentes(),
            self.trabalho(),
            self.corpus_christi(),
            self.independencia() ,
            self.nossa_senhora(),
            self.finados(),
            self.proclamacao_republica(),
            self.natal() ]
```

Verificando se o dia de hoje é um feriado:

```
f = Feriado()

if( date.today() in f.todos() ):
    print( "Hoje eh um Feriado!" )
else:
    print( "Hoje eh um dia util!" )
```

Calculado Data do Carnaval para o ano de `2018`:

```
f = Feriado(2018)
print( f.carnaval() )
```

Listando todos os feriados do ano `2000`:

```
f = Feriado(2000)
print( f.todos() )
```

Comment: A excelente biblioteca [`dateutils`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) também tem uns métodos bem interessantes relacionados a isso e interfaceia bem com o `datetime`. Vale a pena conhecer!

Comment: Sim, eu até posso usar _timedelta()_ para a data final.
Mas ainda terei o problema do ano para feriados fixos. Por exemplo o feriado de 7 de setembro. O ano aqui não interessa, no dia **07/10 00:00** será inicio do feriado e no dia **08/10 00:00** será o fim.
A hora e minuto é importante devido a feriados facultativos que dependendo da empresa, estado, cidade alguns feriados são estendidos até a metade do dia seguinte. E também casos de empresas que não fecham em  algusns feriados. Por isso no meu no projeto os feriados ficaram a cargo do usuário cadastrá-los.